# Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data compatibility with SQL Sever 2016

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I just want to know whether Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data 6.0 version supports SQL Server 2016? I am planning to migrate my SQL Server to 2016 from 2008 , just want to know whether Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data  is compatible with SQL Server 2012.

Appreciate if any one help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data is a high-level abstraction on top of ADO.NET libraries. It supports all versions of Microsoft SQL Server, from 2005 to 2016 out of the box.

Comment: Your first sentence is correct, but what it means is that it will support whatever the underlying installed .NET Framework will support. SQL Server is highly backwards compatible and all old clients can connect with all new versions, but some features might not be available, or only in a modified form (for example Always Encrypted requires .NET 4.6 or later), which is a little more nuanced than supporting all versions out of the box. This matters if the connecting machine will not be upgraded.

Comment: My Dot net application developed in VS2017- with framework 4.6 and MVC 5.0. And its already deployed in the IIS 7.0 server. Still there will be any compatibility issues with this SQL database migration to 2016?

Comment: @Jack009: As far as the Enterprise Library is concerned, no. It's a high-level wrapper that doesn't attempt to translate actual data or inject itself between actual ADO.NET classes. .NET 4.6 fully supports 2016, so it should connect just fine. You should be more concerned with the database itself; the jump from 2008 to 2016 is significant. Even if you don't change the [compatibility level](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level), the engine is still different and you may see performance changes (for good and for bad).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Make sense now. To summarize there wont be any compatibility issues due to the enterprise library which i have used as it should connect or interact with the same way which its doing with 2008 version. Regarding the performance , iam not so worried as the database is not that big. I appreciate your help and time to answer my query.